# How to add html markup into a textarea via checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML

```
<div class="thumbnail">
  <input type="checkbox" name="thing_5" value="valuable" id="thing_5">
  <label for="thing_5">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ac/U.S._Marines_in_Operation_Allen_Brook_(Vietnam_War)_001.jpg">
  </label>
</div>
<div class="thumbnail">
  <input type="checkbox" name="thing_5" value="valuable" id="thing_6">
  <label for="thing_6">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ac/U.S._Marines_in_Operation_Allen_Brook_(Vietnam_War)_001.jpg">
  </label>
</div>
<textarea id='txtarea'></textarea>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.thumbnail :checkbox').change(function() {
    var urls = [];
    $(":checkbox:checked").each(function () {
      urls.push($(this).next("label").find("img").attr("src"));
    });
    if (urls.length)
      $("#txtarea").val("<li>" + urls.join("</li><li>") + "</li>");
    else
        $("#txtarea").val("");
  });
});
```

I need to be able to add `<li>` before the value and also be able to add/remove on checkbox checked/unchecked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only a small change will make it work in this. You should check for the length of the `url` before doing anything on the `textarea` value:

```
if (urls.length)
  $("#txtarea").val("<li>" + urls.join("</li><li>") + "</li>");
else
  $("#txtarea").val("");
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u9myz270/**